# How to test output from a subprocess with RSpec

Tags: ruby, shell, rspec

I want to test that `echo 1` outputs `1`, but

```
expect { `echo 1` }.to output("1").to_stdout
```

does not work. It says it outputs nothing to `stdout`, while

```
expect { print 1 }.to output("1").to_stdout
```

works just fine. Why doesn't the first one work?

Comment: expect { `echo 1` }.to eq '1'   ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expect { `echo 1` }.to output("1").to_stdout
```

doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `echo` runs in a subprocess. RSpec's `output` matcher doesn't handle output from subprocesses by default. But you can use `to_stdout_from_any_process` instead of `to_stdout` to handle subprocesses, although it's a bit slower.
2. `output` only works for output sent to the same standard output stream as the Ruby process. Backticks open a new standard output stream, send the command's standard output to it and return the contents of the stream when the command completes. I don't think you care whether you run your subprocess with backticks or some other way, so just use `system` (which sends the command's standard output to the Ruby process's standard output stream) instead.

Addressing those two points gives us this expectation, which passes:

```
expect { system("echo 1") }.to output("1\n").to_stdout_from_any_process
```

(I had to change the expected value for it to pass, since `echo` adds a newline.)

As MilesStanfield pointed out, in the case you gave it's equivalent and easier to just test the output of backticks rather than use `output`:

```
expect { `echo 1` }.to eq "1\n"
```

That might or might not work in the more complicated case that you presumably have in mind.